# Where does `##x=output number` in PyQGIS script store number?

Tags: pyqgis

I am writing a python script providing a number as output in QGIS toolbox. My question is where does the script put my result number if I use `##result=output number` and assign a number like `result=1.0`?

So the complete script would be something like:

```
##result=output number
result=1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an `output number` or `output string`, you can only assign it via your script (as you have done) and use it as input to another algorithm.

The following excerpt is taken from the book (emphasis mine): ["QGIS By Example" by Alexander Bruy & Daria Svidzinska](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=DfwKCgAAQBAJ&dq=qgis+%23%23output+number&source=gbs_navlinks_s)

> - output number: This represents a numerical value generated by the algorithm. **This value is not saved anywhere and can only be used as the input in another algorithm**. For example, one can implement script to calculate optimal cell size for the vector grid, then the numerical output from such algorithm can be used as input in the Create grid algorithm. An example of its usage is as follows: `##Maximum_value=output number`

Further on, it reads:

> Numerical and string outputs are also called hidden outputs (because they are not shown in QGIS and in Processing's results dialog), and are not automatically initialized with values. You should manually assign the corresponding values to them.

Comment: Thanks. So I guess I just have to use the message log to print the number to the console.

Comment: @ali - Most welcome! You could print it directly to console (`print 'Output Number: ' + str(result)`); or a message bar (`iface.messageBar().pushInfo('Output Number: ' + str(result), '')`; or a message log (`QgsMessageLog.logMessage('Output Number: ' + str(result), 'My Script'`).